# How to specify a random and None value of a boolean parameter

Tags: python, function, random, nonetype

I have some function `a` which has boolean param `b: bool`. This parameter can take either a specified value, an empty value, or a random value.

```
def a(b: Optional[bool] = random_bool()) -> None
  print(b)
```

But if you specify random generation directly in the function declaration, it will always be the same

```
>>> a()
True  # Problem
>>> a()
True  # Problem
>>> a(False)
False
>>> a(True)
True
>>> a(None)
None
```

At first I thought I would assign it an `None` default value and generate a random one already in the function.

```
def a(b: Optional[bool] = None) -> None:
    b = random_bool() if b is None else b
    print(b)
```

But then I wouldn't be able to specify an `None` value

```
>>> a()
True
>>> a()
False
>>> a(False)
False
>>> a(True)
True
>>> a(None)
True # Problem
```

So how can I specify random/specified/empty value in a nice way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At function definition (when python runs), `random_bool()` is called, and the default value defined.  That's why it won't change.

Typically, you would default to `None`, then if not defined perform a default value operation.

I would prefer to allow None, but here's a workaround:

```py
def a(b: Optional[bool] = None, use_random: bool = False) -> None:
    result = b
    if use_random:
        result = random_bool()
    print(result)
```

Or you could default to a value that is not `True`, `False`, or `None`.

```
def a(b: Optional[Union[bool, str]] = "random") -> None:
    result = b
    if result == "random":
        result = random_bool()
    print(result)
```

Comment: In a real case, there may be quite a few parameters that need to be set at random. It seems that the function would become awful

Comment: Try working from a real example if you can.  If you are already accepting True, False, and None as provided values, there is no clean way to signal to the function that you want a random value.